# Search After (pagination) in Elasticsearch when sorting by score

Tags: elasticsearch, search

Search after in elasticsearch must match its sorting parameters in count and order. So I was wondering how to get the score from previous result (example page 1) to use it as a search after for next page.
I faced an issue when using the score of the last document in previous search. The score was 1.0, and since all documents has 1.0 score, the result for next page turned out to be null (empty).

That's actually make sense, since I am asking elasticsearch for results that has lower rank (score) than 1.0 which are zero, so which score do I use to get  the next page.

Note:
I am sorting by score then by TieBreakerID, so one possible solution is using high value (say 1000) for score.

Comment: Why can't you use the from parameter to get results at the offset?

Comment: For performance reason, from and size cannot be used in my case, according to this docs: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-search-after

Comment: Are you sure that searching by score would be any faster?  Also, note that scores are NOT reproducible according to the docs (assuming no workarounds). This means your approach may not work. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/consistent-scoring.html

Comment: I totally agree with you Dennis, scores might differ in every request, which make it unreliable as a search after parameter. So what do you suggest to use for pagination when sorting by relevance?

Comment: It depends on your use case.  In Search, it's rare to need to look past the first few pages.  "From" will be fine if you are not looking past the first few pages.  Take a look at Scroll API, which allows you to efficiently iterate through the entire dataset.  Note that it is expensive to keep the scroll context alive, so it's not really meant for pagination, more for iteration.  However, you could use scroll api to cache the results to your application?  Other than that, I don't think there are any other supported methods.  Let me know if that doesn't solve your use case.

Comment: Thanks Dennis
I think I will stick with from and size mechanism. Since I could not find any better way yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're doing sounds like it should work, as [explained by an Elastic team member](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/using-search-after-for-pagination-where-you-sort-by-score/146233/2). It works for me (in ES 7.7) even with tied scores when using the document ID (copied into another indexed field) as a tiebreaker. It's true that indexing additional documents while paginating will make your scores slightly unstable, but not likely enough to cause a significant problem for an end user. If you need it to be reliable for a batch job, the Scroll API is the better choice.

```
{
    "query": {
        ...
    },
    "search_after": [
        12.276552,
        14173
    ],
    "sort": [
        { "_score": "desc" },
        { "id": "asc" }
    ]
}
```